# Show / Hide a CSS element depending on the date

Tags: javascript, jquery, datetime

I am working on a list with 3 rows and I need to show the 2nd element on the list only from day 1 to day 5 each Month. I target the pseudo element li:nth-child(2) and works on CSS fine if I change something on this element but It does't work if I call it using Js.

I used this code first:

```
function ShowOnTime(from, to, element){

        var a = new Date(); 
        var now = a.getDate(); 

        if( now <= from || now >= to ){
            $(element).hide();
        }else{
            $(element).show();
        }

}


$(document).ready(function(){
        ShowOnTime(1,5,"li:nth-child(2)"); //Show first 5 days a month; 
});
```

But it seems to be old as `if( now < from || now > to )`   Doesn't work . Then my other attempt is:

```
$(document).ready(function() 
{
 
 var pDate = pDate.getDate();

 if 
   // show only the first 5 days of the month
   ((pDate >= 5)) 
   {
   $("li:nth-child(2)").hide();
   }
   else{
        $("li:nth-child(2)").show();
    }
});
```

Without success either. I have seen another workarounds here but nothing like I need.
Sal

Comment: `<=` and `>=` should be `<` and `>`. Your code will hide the element on day 1 and 5.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use toggle instead of if/else here to show/hide.
I put a console log in to show values and commented out code to "force" it to show.  I also updated to the recommended form of jQuery document ready.

```js
function ShowOnTime(from, to, element) {
  let now = new Date().getDate();
  // uncomment to simulate day 2 :
  // now = now - now + 2;
  console.log(now, from, to, `I have ${$(element).text()} text`);
  $(element).toggle((now >= from && now <= to));
}


$(function() {
  ShowOnTime(1, 5, "li:nth-child(2)"); //Show first 5 days a month; 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
  <li>4</li>
  <li>5</li>
  <li>6</li>
  <li>7</li>
  <li>8</li>
  <li>9</li>
  <li>10</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Great, thanks Mark. At first I had a Console error but it was matter of update JQerry version.

Comment: Question did not specify so I just defaulted to the most recent in the Snippet editor.